# Is there a measure of covariance for larger dimensions?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Can you measure the covariance of three or more variables simultanesously?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want the resulting statistic to represent. Is a Principal Components Analysis sufficient?

Comment: Check [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57998/correlation-between-3-variables) out.

Comment: @Stat Thank you for that link: it's a nice and natural theoretical answer. Interpreting that multivariate cumulant is challenging, though. It's basically the expectation of the product of the centered variables. Yes, it will be large when all the variables tend to be large together or small together--but it will also be large when, say, any two of the variables are small while the third is large. Thus it no longer has the meaning one would desire to impute to a "covariance." This suggests the question needs to be clarified: phil12, what exactly do you mean by a multivariate "covariance"?

Comment: Note that [total correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_correlation) has been defined. I think the question is valid, and the lack of clarity is debatable.